# How to show all possible names given a few a letters in different positions?

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and I want to know how can I generate all possible names/words given a few letters in different positions using Python.

For example:
A _ _ r _  w

I want to see all of the possible names I can create with these letters in their respective positions... (Btw,  the possible names you could generate from that is "Andrew", "Ambrew", "Aberow" (yeah, i dont know if this name/word exist hahah, but i hope you get the point)

My problem is I don't know where to start (although I already learned some basics of python) I just don't know what exact mechanics or concepts I will use.

Comment: Are you sure "Andrei" is a valid possible name?

Comment: oh my i'm sorry HAHAHA. gonna edit that, wait.

Comment: do you have a fixed list of names/words available? or any other way to know which word is a considered a valid "name/word"? or you just want any word in this patern such that `Aaaraw, Aaarbw, ...` would also be generated?

Comment: If you have some list of names/words, you can make your pattern into regex and search the list. | For generating all words (letter combinations) - itertools.product? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) Generate all products of missing letters length, then put your known characters and maybe analyse the word (as Daniel said in the meantime, you'll get stuff like Aaaraw, Aaarbw, Aaarcw... and so on until Azzrzw).

Comment: @Daniel For your second question, my answer is Yes. Yes I want any word in this pattern such as Aaaraw, Aaarbw, .... The reason for this is I dont have a fixed list, and I just want myself to assess if that name is valid. (Btw, the purpose of the program in my mind is find all the possible names or words or even non-existing words in that pattern, and I don't have lists of names that is valid)

Answer (score 2):

One way using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase as l

names = ["".join(p) for p in product("A", l, l, "r", l, "w")]
```

Output:

```
['Aaaraw',
 'Aaarbw',
 'Aaarcw',
 'Aaardw',
 'Aaarew',
 'Aaarfw',
 ...]
```

This creates *all* possible cases of `26 ** 3` (3 empty spots):

```
len(names) == 26 ** 3
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and do something like this. I didn't write the full code to get every possibility, but you might be able to get an idea.

```
blank_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
blank_2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
count_1 = 0
count_2 = 0

for i in blank_1:
    name = "A {} {} w".format(blank_1[count_1], blank_2[count_2])
    count_1 = count_1+1
    print(name)
```

So you will get an output like this,

```
A a a w
A b a w
A c a w
A d a w
A e a w
```

Edit: This will not give every name that's real, but every possible combinations. for example: `A a a W` is not a real name

Comment: I have a kinda noob question... Why there is no "A a b w" output? That is also valid isn't it? or what I mean is in that certain codes, it must show "A a b w" because that is also a possibility? (I don't really know if my question is right)

Comment: @user16703489 Yes you are right "A a b w" will be an output. I only added for the 2nd letter to change. There's probably a easier way to do this tho...

Answer (score -1):

You can check if they belong to a list of names (find them easily online). Here is a working example, which returns
`['andrew', 'amdrew', 'adnrew']` (third one strange ahah) for your example

```
f = open("names.txt","r")
name_i = "A__r_w".lower()
liste_name = []

for line in f.readlines():
    line = line[:-1].lower() #skip the space at the end of the line
    if len(line) == len(name_i): #avoid checking if lengths are different
        boolean = True
        for i in range(len(name_i)):
            if name_i[i] != "_" and name_i[i] != line[i]:
                boolean = False # is not possible
        if boolean:
            liste_name.append(line)
print(liste_name)
f.close()
```

Download the txt here : https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/roche/courses/s15si335/proj1/files.php%3Ff=names.txt&downloadcode=yes

Feel free to ask questions :)

Comment: ahmmm, how can I make python opens the "names.txt" it shows an error when I run it.

Comment: you just have to download the link at the end of my post, https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/roche/courses/s15si335/proj1/files.php%3Ff=names.txt&downloadcode=yes , either copy/paste it in a names.txt file or download it, place it in the same folder as the script and run it